# Mysql unexpected token error on importing SQL file

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

I want to import my `mydatabase.sql` file to my new server. I'm testing with my old server; importing progress is ok.  However, my new server returns a lot of error messages..

They are:

```
A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near "2012" at position 8182)
9 values were expected, but found 5. (near "(" at position 8093)
Unexpected token. (near "/" at position 8186)
Unexpected token. (near "12" at position 8187)
Unexpected token. (near "/" at position 8189)
Unexpected token. (near "foto_2723" at position 8190)
Unexpected token. (near "', '', 27236, '', '" at position 8209)
Unexpected token. (near "1383142632" at position 8228)
Unexpected token. (near "', '" at position 8238)
Unexpected token. (near "85.105" at position 8242)
Unexpected token. (near ".7" at position 8248)
```

Without providing the `mydatabase.sql` file, is there anything about these errors that could suggest a problem?

Comment: how was the mydatabase.sql produced, and what mechanism are you using to import it to the new server?

Comment: I suggest you to share relevant sections of the file with us.

Comment: @suing i export file via phpmyadmin in my old server..and trying to import via phpmyadmin in my new sever (one of cpanel, other ise plesk)

Comment: @Shadow i dont know what is 'position' ? its not looking like LINE (?)

Comment: are the databases on the same technology? MySQL vs MariaDB, etc, different databases will use different syntax... so if different technologies are in play, it will not work unless some conversion is done.

Comment: @stackers_alti the position of the character within the text file from the beginning of the file.

Comment: @suing they are all MYSQL

Comment: @Shadow so; how can i count/detect 8000. character in .SQL file?

Comment: can you check if the MySQL versions of the two DBs are the same, I've run into issues were i cannot import of the version of source dump is older, due to deprecated syntax

Comment: to find nth character, use notepad++ and Press Crtl-G and choose Offset. Enter 8182.

Comment: @Suing phpmyadmin version 4.0.10.7 > version version 4.5.0.2

Comment: @Suing im using macbook (textedit); i couldnt find it :(

Comment: Then get a proper code editor! How did you even try to debug the errors if you cannot find the corresponding locations in the file?

Comment: stackers, there are consecutive string fragments in the error out put you're showing. you can tell by comparing position values and string lengths /12/foto_2723  is one.   ', '', 27236, '', ' is the second and 1383142632', '85.105.7 is the third. Maybe search for one of those strings in your file to get into the neighborhood of where things went wrong? You'll see a pattern of insert statements and, given that MySQL is going to use commas and quotes to logical parse your data, try to see if there aren't commas and quotes IN your data which may be causing confusion.

Comment: thank you, but that is phpmyadmin version, please find your mysql version by clicking on the "SQL" tab of phpmyadmin, and running the following command: SELECT VERSION();  (please include the semicolon at the end of the statement; do this for both server and report your findings.